# Select prototypes before main()

Tags: regex, vim

I need a regex to select the prototypes before `main()`. So for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                       

char ga[] = "abcdefghijklm";                                             

void my_array_func(char ca[10]);                                          
void my_pointer_func(char *pa);                                           

int main()                                                               
{                                                                        
   /* code */                       

   return 0;                                                            
}
```

There is an empty line above and below the prototypes. The selected text should be

```
void my_array_func(char ca[10]);                                          
void my_pointer_func(char *pa);
```

my current attempt in Vim is:

```
^\w\_.\{-}\(^\nint main\)\@=
```

but this matches

```
char ga[] = "abcdefghijklm";                                             

void my_array_func(char ca[10]);                                          
void my_pointer_func(char *pa);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the flexibility required. You can begin solving problems like this by analyzing your constraints. What makes a bunch of characters to be considered a function declaration? One simple observation points to lines ending in `);` before `int main` considering the context of your example.

To match multiple lines ending in `);`:

```
/\v(.*\);\n)+
```

If they may contain additional spaces before or after the `;` (bad!), the `\_s` comes in handy since it matches whitespace and newlines. This also allows empty lines between prototype lines:

```
/\v(.*\)\s*;\_s{-})+
```

Note the use of `{-}` instead of `*` to avoid grabbing extra whitespace (ungreedy, shortest match to satisfy). To enforce those lines come before `int main`, possibly preceded by more whitespace (like empty lines) but stopping before such whitespace:

```
/\v(.*\)\s*;\_s{-})+\ze\_s*int\_s+main
```

To sum it up, a simple `/\v(.*\);\n)+` will match your prototypes in the code posted. The more complex version presented above will match them even if formatted like so:

```
void my_array_func(char ca[10]);

void my_pointer_func(char *pa) ;


int
main()                                          
{
    /* ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
/^$\n\zs.*\n.*\ze\n\nint main
```

But may need some refining, it does not check if there is actually a valid text on the 2 lines you want to select. But the important part here is `:h \zs` and `:h \ze`

Comment: Thank you. However this regex only seems to work for two prototypes. If I add or remove a prototype this regex will not match.

Comment: True that, shouldn't be that hard, `^$\n\(^.*\n\)\{-}\ze$\nint main` but the funny thing is, I have the same problem as you, the non greedy is somehow not working

Comment: Ok after some time I figured out the required regex: `\v(^.+\n)+\ze\nint main`

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, your solution seems fine and skips the problematic part, but now i am stuck with why the non-greedy modifier is not working as intended ;-)

Comment: If someone is interested, asked about it on vi se https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17082/non-greedy-is-greedy

Comment: DoktorOSwaldo There is no problem with `\{-}` at all. It does work as intended. The problem is where your match starts. It starts in an empty line and there is one right above `char ga[]`, so it starts there. Since it allows empty lines (`.*`) if matches everything. @Sergio's solution with `.+` doesn't allow empty lines other than the one explicitly written.

Comment: In other words, being non-greedy doesn't mean the shortest possible match. Engines don't work like that. It just means the shortest continuation or replication after it started matching that satisfies the next condition. Yours begins matching earlier than his, and greediness does not apply to the start but to the replication of the atom. To the engines eyes: you start matching and if it matches, jump to the next condition. If the next condition is replicate this in a non-greedy fashion, it will replicate until the next condition meets and that's it. It won't change the start.

Comment: @sidyll that's exactly the information I was missing, thank you very much